# How to use wp db export and import together?

Tags: wp-cli

When I use **WP-CLI** I'm having some issues with the wp db export and wp db import commands.

I have a local site on my desktop that I would like to migrate to my laptop so I can work on it. So I go on my desktop, navigate to the appropriate directory and type `wp db export`. It is a success and creates the file: `ccv3-2018-07-12-4e523fb.sql`

Now here is the part I don't get. I copy paste the SQL file that it creates on my desktop to my laptops directory where the local website resides. I type `wp db import ccv3-2018-07-12-4e523fb.sql --authors=skip` and then I get:

> Starting the import process... Error: This does not appear to be a WXR
>   file, missing/invalid WXR version number

After googling this issue it looks like the file it's trying to import should be an XML file, but after looking at the file I get when I use `wp db export` reveals an actual SQL file.

So what gives? What should I be doing to migrate databases with WP-CLI?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct commands? `wp import` expects a WXR file, while `wp db import` is for SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are mixing [`wp db import`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/import/) with [`wp import`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/import/).

`wp import` indeed expects an WordPress Extended RSS (WXR) file
 as input. Whereas `wp db import` doesn't know of an `--authors` option.

Just use `wp db import ccv3-2018-07-12-4e523fb.sql` and everything should be fine.